# Mule - Getting session property from transfomer

Tags: mule, mule-component

How do I replace this deprecated method with something that is not?

```
public class StrTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
        LOGGER.debug("transformMessage");
        //getSessionProperty is deprecated. Javadocs say, I can use muleSession
        //but muleSession is not available from this method.
        //Any ideas?
        return message.getSessionProperty("TEST_PROPERTY");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the session property as follows:

```
message.getProperty("myProperty", PropertyScope.SESSION);
```